# Cannot open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server': file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql-server, macos

I keep getting error when connecting to mssql with python on macos:

> DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]'Cannot open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server': file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
> (Background of this error: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/dbapi)

I also applied execute operations but it didn't fix:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver16#17

Has anyone had this problem before and can help me?

```
import pyodbc as po
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

server = "localhost"
db = "master"
user = **
pwd = **

driver_name = ''
driver_names = [x for x in pyodbc.drivers()]
if driver_names:
    driver_name = driver_names[0]


# Connection string
cnxn = po.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=' +
        server+';DATABASE='+db+';UID='+user+';PWD=' + pwd)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
 
# Fetch data into a cursor
cursor.execute("SELECT TOP (10) PersonID, FullName, PhoneNumber, \
    EmailAddress FROM WideWorldImporters.Application.People ORDER BY PersonID DESC;")
 
# iterate the cursor
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row:
    # Print the row
    print(str(row[0]) + ", " + str(row[1] or '') + ", " + str(row[2] or '') + ", " + str(row[3] or ''))
    row = cursor.fetchone()
 
# Close the cursor and delete it
cursor.close()
del cursor
 
# Close the database connection
cnxn.close()
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like `msodbcsql17` installed properly. What version of macOS are you using? What's the output of `find /usr/local/{include,lib,opt,share} -name "*msodbc*"` from `bash` in a Terminal window? (Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76826814/edit) your question to include that output.)

Comment: Output is:

(base) hunkargencyildiz@Hunkar-MacBook-Air ~ % find /usr/local/lib -name "*msodbc*"

/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib